# Read file until regex in changelog file using bash

Tags: regex, shell, changelog

I want to get content in file until find a regex in content. I need this to report my last changelog

Example:

```
## <small>0.27.3 (2019-03-18)</small>

* Fix integration tests
* Change log message


## <small>0.27.2 (2019-03-18)</small>

* Change find to filter
* Fix bug in typo
* Format message in request
```

I want a regex to return oly the content of my latest version. Example:

```
## <small>0.27.3 (2019-03-18)</small>

* Fix integration tests
* Change log message
```

How can I make this using sed, grep or awk?

Thanks for this

Edit:

I can made it:

```sh
CHANGELOG_MESSAGE=$(head -n 1 CHANGELOG.md)$(head -n 20 CHANGELOG.md | tail -n 19 | sed '/##/q' | awk '!/##/')
```

I think that this solution is a few complex, but works

Comment: If you have found an answer - feel free to post the answer to your own question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
sed '1p;1,/^##/!d;/##/d' CHANGELOG.md
```

explanation

```
1p             # print first line
;           
1,/^##/!d      # delete everything after second ##-line
;               
/##/d          # delete all lines start with ##
```

output

```
## <small>0.27.3 (2019-03-18)</small>

* Fix integration tests
* Change log message
```